# How to check only folders inside the folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-2.7, directory

I'm trying to find out the proper solution to check only folders inside the folder and read only XML files.

My code:

```
data= os.listdir('./home/')
for packs in data:
    file=open('./home/' + packs + '/files' + 'data.xml', 'r') #i have 100's of folders inside home
    all_file=file.read()
```

Output: It reads all the folders as per requirement but I have 3 csv and 2 text files in the folder `home`. My code is also reading those files and gives an error. I don't want to read those, is there any methods to read only XML files.

Comment: Use [`globl.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to get the list of `*.xml` files you want.

Comment: use python's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. sth similar to this : ```Path(main_folder).rglob('*.xml')```. Read the link provided for guidance